# Java - Why does my print statement not run

Tags: java, swing

So this is my code:

```
System.out.println("System Exiting...");
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
long disired = current + 4000;
boolean done = false;
while (!done)
{
    current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (current == disired)
    {
        done = true;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the print statement doesn't run, well it does run, but it runs at the same time as the exit statement, so you don't see it

[EDIT] Ok, so i just ran this code in its own file(with nothing else), and it works as i want, it prints "system Exiting..." it waits 4 seconds, and the code exits.
so it has to be something to do with the fact that i have this code inside an event listener

Comment: try it on a very, veeeeeeeery slow computer, and you might get to see it longer.

Answer (score 2):

Your if condition is *much* too restrictive since your code will almost never get the times to be exactly equal, but the change needed is very simple:

Change

```
// hitting this exactly is like finding the proverbial needle
// in the haystack -- almost impossible to do.
if (current == disired)
```

to

```
// this is guaranteed to work.
// note if this is in English, you'll want to change disired to desired
if (current >= disired)
```

Having said this, your `while (true)` loop is not a good thing to do as it will needlessly tie up the CPU with empty cycles. Instead use some type of event notification or call-back system like ChangeListener or a PropertyChangeListener or a Timer.

---

You state:

> yes it is within a swing GUI

You're calling  a long `while (true)` block of code on the Swing event thread, rendering this thread ineffective. Since the event thread is responsible for all Swing graphics and user interactions, this effectively freezes your GUI until the while loop completes. The solution is obvious: 1) use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for your delay, not a while true loop (this is the callback mechanism that I mentioned in my original answer), and 2) in the future, please give us this important relevant information with the original question since it changes the entire nature of the question.

e.g.

```
// caveat: code not tested
System.out.println("System Exiting...");
int delay = 4 * 1000;
new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out. println("Exited");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}).start();
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestDelayedExit extends JPanel {
   private static final int GAP = 100;

   public TestDelayedExit() {
      add(new JButton(new DisposeAction("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X)));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestDelayedExit");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestDelayedExit());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

   private class DisposeAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int count = 4;
      private Timer timer;
      public DisposeAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // for alt-key combo
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
            return;
         }
         final Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
         int timerDelay = 1000;         
         putValue(NAME, String.valueOf(count));
         timer = new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (count == 0) {
                  ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                  // this will not work for JMenuItems, and for that
                  // you would need to get the pop up window's parent component
                  Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(c);
                  if (win != null) {
                     win.dispose();
                  }
               } else {
                  count--;
                  putValue(NAME, String.valueOf(count));
               }
            }
         });
         timer.start();
      }
   }       
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, but this if isn't the problem, as the code inside the if statement always run (the code exits), the problem is that the print line, the first line of code, doesn't run until after the while loop.

Comment: @JacobGroves: You're saying that the `System.out.println("System Exiting...");` doesn't appear until after 4 seconds, after the while loop? If so, then please create and post a minimal program that we can run unaltered and that demonstrates your problem. Also, is this code within a Swing GUI? If so, you'd be breaking Swing threading rules by having a `while (true)` loop on the event thread.

Comment: @JacobGroves: `"so it has to be something to do with the fact that i have this code inside an event listener"` -- I'm even more suspicious that you may have a Swing GUI and threading issues going on. Please be sure to tell us all the important details of your problem so that we can better understand it and better be able to help you.

Comment: I think what is not quite clicking is when the GUI freezes, it means printing to the screen also freezes. So, the GUI freezes for 4 seconds causing the print to not get rendered. Then the program exits right as rending would begin.

Comment: Thank you, the only other question i would ask is, if the while loop does in essence freeze the JFrame, why does it not execute the code before the while loop then freeze it? that makes more sense to me, or is there some reason for the loop being executed first?

Comment: @JacobGroves: if you're talking about a println, yes, that doesn't make sense as the println should display before the while loop runs. If you're talking about code that draws something to the GUI (again, your question never states this), then it makes perfect sense that it will not display.